# Is /usr/bin/etags severely out of date in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, emacs, open-source

Is /usr/bin/etags severely out of date in Yosemite?  If so, what is the easiest way to get an up-to-date version of etags, to use with Emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com/?

I am using:

GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2014-10-20 on builder10-9.porkrind.org.
Yosemite 10.10.1

Answer (score 2):

Emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com/ comes with a recent etags:

```
$find /Applications/Emacs.app -name etags\*
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-i386-10_5/etags
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-powerpc-10_4/etags
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_5/etags
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_7/etags
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9/etags
[...]
```

It's the corresponding version to emacs:

```
$ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9/etags --version
etags (GNU Emacs 24.4)
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Would using [ctags](http://usevim.com/2013/01/18/tags/) from [homebrew](http://brew.sh) be a sufficient replacement? It is quite up to date (Exuberant Ctags 5.8) and trivial to install if you have Xcode already and then install the brew package manager. It's [manual page](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html) clearly indicates that it works with Emacs.

Comment: The man page for etags says "The  etags  program  is  used  to create a tag table file, in a format understood by emacs(1); the ctags program is used to create a similar table in a format understood by
vi(1).

Comment: @AlanWehmann The ctags package I recommended works with emacs. Try it, you'll like it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why etags is out of date is that the emacs version installed on a Mac by default is also severely out of date.

Emacs comes with etags, so when you install emacs via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), you get a recent etags. But I would expect that emacsforosx also comes with etags.

I *assume* that, if you look in the application folder, you will find etags somewhere there. Then it is only an issuer of calling this etags binary.

Comment: I looked for an etags binary that might have come with emacsforosx.  I didn't find one.